# DD-WRT OpenVPN - Unable to access lan or internet

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn, dd-wrt

I have an issue with my vpn server setup. After 2 days, I ditched the gui on dd-wrt and made a config for bridget connection that worked, but not on iPhone (they do not support it). So I decided to switch to the TUN. Sever is running, I can connect, but there two problems -

1. Cannot access lan
2. Cannot access internet / unless I remove dhcp-option from the server

My LAN is 192.168.1.0/24 and VPN net 192.168.2.0/24
This is my server setup

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1" 
server 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1" 

mode server
proto udp4
port 1194 
dev tun0 
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
auth SHA256
comp-lzo yes
script-security 2
keepalive 10 120 
daemon 
verb 5 

dh /tmp/openvpn/dh.pem 
ca /tmp/openvpn/ca.crt 
cert /tmp/openvpn/cert.pem 
key /tmp/openvpn/key.pem
```

Firewall script

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

And client settings

```
remote router-ip 1194

client 
dev tun0
proto udp 
resolv-retry infinite 
nobind 
persist-key 
persist-tun 
float
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
comp-lzo yes
verb 5

ca ca.crt 
cert client1.crt 
key client1.key 

remote-cert-tls server
```

Route table

```
default via XX.XXX.XXX.XXX dev vlan2
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/26 dev vlan2  proto kernel  scope link  src XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 169.254.255.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.2.2 dev tun0
192.168.2.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
```

My phone droping accessing the LAN

```
Sep 16 14:46:03 DD-WRT kern.warn kernel: DROP IN=tun0 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.2.6 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=9878 PROTO=UDP SPT=64708 DPT=53 LEN=40
Sep 16 14:46:03 DD-WRT kern.warn kernel: DROP IN=tun0 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.2.6 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=35922 PROTO=UDP SPT=49210 DPT=53 LEN=56
Sep 16 14:46:05 DD-WRT kern.warn kernel: DROP IN=tun0 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.2.6 DST=192.168.1.1 LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=1652 PROTO=UDP SPT=49210 DPT=53 LEN=56
```

Any idea whaty might be the issue here? :/ My guess is that the 2.0 cannon talk to the 1.0 network, but I have no clue how to edit the iptables to make it work :/.

Answer (score 0):

So after 2 days, I found a working solution :D

VPN Server config

```
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 5.135.183.146" 
push "dhcp-option DNS 151.80.147.153" 
server 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1" 

management localhost 5001
mode server
proto udp4
port 1194 
dev tun0 
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256
auth SHA256
comp-lzo yes
script-security 2
keepalive 10 120 
daemon 
verb 5 

dh /tmp/openvpn/dh.pem 
ca /tmp/openvpn/ca.crt 
cert /tmp/openvpn/cert.pem 
key /tmp/openvpn/key.pem
```

Firewall script

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 2 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -I FORWARD 1 --source 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```